# How can I include html tab into Paginator cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp, pagination

I am using paginator cakephp it work correctly but, I have a menu like that:

[image: menu]

So the pagination is in `tab-2`, when I click next that reload the page and automatically go to tab-1, there is a solution to keep it going to tab-2 ??

I was trying to use `projectURL#tab-2` but still not work
this is the controller code:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'conditions' => array('user2' => $userId),
            'order' => array('Message.timestamp' => 'DESC'),
            'recursive' => 2 ,
            'limit' => 8
        );
// similaire à un findAll(), mais récupère les résultats paginés
$message = $this->Paginator->paginate('Message');
```

And this is the view code:

```
<?php foreach ($message as $recep){ ...} ?>
<ul class="pagination" style="margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 2%;">
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('précédent'), array('tag' => 'li'), null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '','currentTag' => 'a', 'currentClass' => 'active','tag' => 'li','first' => 1));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('suivant'), array('tag' => 'li','currentClass' => 'disabled'), null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using url#hash should work if you also add a bit of javascript to the page:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.hash) { //A hash exists in the url
        var hash = window.location.hash; //Now has the #hash part of the url
        //Code to open the tab here
    }
}
```